# Exact Match of user-input string in Ansible Conditional statements

Tags: ansible, conditional-statements

In my case, I have a playbook similar to below one to get the list of profiles, to display the list of profiles and fail the task when a profile specified by the user through survey/ as extra variable (var name is: userinput ) exists in the available profiles.

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: no
  become: true
  tasks: 
    - name: Getting the list of Profiles
      shell: some command to get the list of profiles
      register: output
      
    - name: Printing the list of profiles
      debug:
        msg: "{{output.stdout_lines}}"
        
    - name: Failing the task when the specified profile already exists
      fail:
        msg: The Profile {{userinput}} already exists
      when: 'Profile={{userinput}}' in output.stdout
...
```

Let us say the list of profiles displayed is as follows.

```
"msg":[
"Profiles_List"
"  Profile=TESTPROFILE1",
"  Profile=TESTPROFILE2",
"  Profile=TESTPROFILE3"
]
```

The problem here is, even when userinput is given as "TESTPROFILE", it is finding the match (partially) and failing the last task of the playbook.  
The requirement is that the last task in the playbook should fail when the exact match is found (that is when one of exact values avaible in the list is specified by the user)

Can someone please let me know how to achieve this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code, `output.stdout` is very probably a string not a list. This is the reason the condition doesn't work. Parse the list of the profiles first. Given the list of the profiles

```yaml
    Profiles_List:
      - Profile=TESTPROFILE1
      - Profile=TESTPROFILE2
      - Profile=TESTPROFILE3
```

the condition below works as expected

```yaml
    - name: Fail when profile already exists
      fail:
        msg: "The Profile {{ userinput }} already exists"
      when: _profile in Profiles_List
      vars:
        _profile: "Profile={{ userinput }}"
```

---

Q: ***"Parse the list of profiles."***

A: Given the data

```yaml
output.stdout_lines:
  - Profiles_List
  - '  Profile=TESTPROFILE1'
  - '  Profile=TESTPROFILE2'
  - '  Profile=TESTPROFILE3'
```

- Get the profiles

```yaml
Profiles: "{{ output.stdout_lines[1:]|map('trim')|list }}"
```

gives

```yaml
Profiles:
  - Profile=TESTPROFILE1
  - Profile=TESTPROFILE2
  - Profile=TESTPROFILE3
```

- Parse the items

```yaml
Profiles_List: "{{ Profiles|map('split', '=')|map('last')|list }}"
```

gives

```yaml
Profiles_List:
  - TESTPROFILE1
  - TESTPROFILE2
  - TESTPROFILE3
```

- Create dictionaries

```yaml
Profiles_Dict: "{{ Profiles_List|map('community.general.dict_kv', 'profile')|list }}"
```

gives

```yaml
Profiles_Dict:
  - profile: TESTPROFILE1
  - profile: TESTPROFILE2
  - profile: TESTPROFILE3
```

Comment: Could you please let me know how to get the list of profiles from output.stdout string data ? I mean How to parse the list of Profiles ?

Comment: Sure. I added a few examples of how to create various structures.